# I want my JSS app to be the homepage

Tags: jss

I would like to see my app when I go to my local root URL (in anonymous mode).

I deleted the Home website from the admin. 
So currently I have this tree:

[image: Sitecore Tree]

my-app.config looks like this:

[image: my app config]

However, when I go to my URL I have this error:
"**The layout for the requested document was not found**"

How can I do, to have */sitecore/content/my-app/home* as my homepage ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you hostname matches your IIS binding.
2. When you click on preview, make sure you selected sitecore/content/my-app/home item and not sitecore/content/my-app/

Comment: Thanks Mohamed ! I changed my hostname to hostName="vue.jss" (same as my URL). And, now I can enjoy my app :)

Comment: FWIW if you want it to be the default homepage for any binding, remove `hostName` entirely and you'll get it.